# Spring Actuator /info returns an empty body

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

How to add custom metrics to `/info` endpoint in `Spring Boot` **2.7.0** *Actuator*?

**pom.xml**

```xml
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Currently have the following related to actuator.

**application.properties**

```
info.app.version=@project.version@

management.endpoint.info.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info,health
```

I have verified that the `info.app.version` property can be retrieved using `@Value`. But despite this I am only getting an empty response on `/info`.

Response header:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Type: application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v3+json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Wed, 15 Jun 2022 04:12:47 GMT


* Received 7 B chunk
* Received 5 B chunk
* Connection #26 to host localhost left intact
```

Response body :

```
{}
```

---

My understanding is any property under `info` is included in `/info` endpoint. Or does this not work on actuator v2+ ?
[Source](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators#4-info-endpoint)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [Spring Boot 2.6 Release Notes - Actuator Env InfoContributor Disabled by Default](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes#actuator-env-infocontributor-disabled-by-default)

You need to enable the *info env* property:

```
management.info.env.enabled=true
```

Answer (score 4):

Latest spring boot requires two things to be set up:

1- exposing the endpoint in `application.properties` file:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info, health
```

You can use a wildcard and expose all endpoints if you want

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

2- enabling info.env in `application.properties`:

```
management.info.env.enabled=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Our project includes the git-commit-id-plugin, which puts in the response body of the actuator some data regarding the last commit.

I was running a new Maven project which didn't still have the. git/ folder, therefore the plugin couldn't do its job, and the whole endpoint's response was an empty body. So, include in your checklist the fact that all the contributors to /admin/info/ are correctly configured.