# Empty response from /actuator/info

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have spring boot app
I wanted to add info details for /actuator/info
According to Spring Boot documentation it can be done as following

```
management.endpoint.info.java.enabled=true
```

I have also defined :

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info, health
```

But when accessing /actuator/info , I got empty response `{}`
Is there something missing in definition ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Actuator /info returns an empty body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72625911/spring-actuator-info-returns-an-empty-body)

Comment: The property is `management.info.java.enabled` not what you have.\

Comment: I tried both management.info.java.enabled and management.endpoint.info.java.enabled - same result